# Using PortB as a sink, not working

Tags: pins, atmega328

Out of ideas here, i try using PB0-3 as sinks for a LED matrix and the pins just won't sink.

My test code:

```
void setup() {
  //bitClear(SPCR, 6);
  pinMode(PD5, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(PB0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PB1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PB2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(PB3, OUTPUT);

  digitalWrite(PB0, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PB1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PB2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(PB3, LOW);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(PD5, HIGH);
  delay(1000);            
  digitalWrite(PD5, LOW); 
  delay(1000);            
}
```

(Using bog standard Blink as a starting point for tests)

My controller is an ATMega328P programmed using USBaspLoader on my own PCB.

If i connect the physical pin that should be sinking with a piece of wire to ground the LED starts blinking, so the "sending" part seems to work but the "receiving" part doesn't.
As you can see i tried manually disabling the SPI port, no luck either.
I tried different controllers, among them a good old ATMega8-16, nothing seems to work.
I even breadboarded a test circuit but no luck, PortB wont sink.

Comment: Why are you using the likes of `PB3` with `digitalWrite()` etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PB3` etc don't refer to Arduino pins. Instead they refer to the bits in the internal registers.

To use `digitalWrite()` etc you must use *Arduino pins* not internal register bit numbers.

The pin to port/bit mapping is defined by what board you have selected, and if you want to look it up you should examine the `pins_arduino.h` file for your selected board.

Comment: Thanks, i thought, because the compiler wasn't complaining, that they where defined as such. Is there some way to look at the intermediate code?

Comment: You mean the assembly code? You can disassemble the elf file with `avr-objdump -S` I guess, but that's probably not of any help to you.  In general `PBx` is defined as `x` (`PB3` is defined as `3`) and is intended to be used as `PORTB |= (1 << PB3)`.